# After running a mathematical function, how do I not display it to the screen?

Tags: c++

I apologize in advance for the terrible title, it's hard to find a few words that encapsulate my issue effectively. 
I have to do a programming project for making a cash register. After I find the total amount of money for the items, I have to input a change value, and make change with twenties, tens, fives, singles, quarters, dimes, nickels, and pennies. I have done the programming to calculate the change in bills and coins, but my professor wants us to not include the bills or coins if there aren't any being returned.

Here is my code so far for it-

```
void find_change(){
double change_given, updated_price, coin_price;
//item_price_total = 318.32;    keep this in here for testing purposes
//change_given = 405.23;        ' '
int   twenties,
        tens,
        fives,
        singles,
        quarters,
        dimes,
        nickels,
        pennies;
//finds the change in bills

do{
    cout << "How much change is given? " << endl;
    while(!(cin >> change_given)){                //tests to make sure value entered can be used
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cout << "Invalid input.  Try again: ";
    }

    if(change_given < item_price_total){
        cout << "You did not give the machine enough money" << endl;
    }
}while(change_given < item_price_total);

updated_price =change_given-item_price_total;
cout << "The total price is: " << item_price_total << endl;
cout << "The change given is: " << change_given << endl;
cout << "The change back will be: " << updated_price << endl;
twenties = updated_price / 20;
cout << "Twenties: " << twenties << endl;
updated_price = updated_price -(twenties *20);
tens = updated_price/10;
cout << "Tens: " << tens << endl;
updated_price = updated_price - (tens*10);
fives = updated_price/5;
cout << "Fives: " << fives << endl;
updated_price = updated_price - (fives*5);
singles = updated_price/1;
cout << "Singles: " << singles << endl;
updated_price = updated_price - (singles*1);

//this part finds the coins left
coin_price = updated_price * 100;
//finds the change in coins
quarters = coin_price/25;
cout << "Quarters: " << quarters << endl;
coin_price = coin_price - (quarters*25);
dimes = coin_price/10;
cout << "Dimes: " << dimes << endl;
coin_price = coin_price - (dimes*10);
nickels = coin_price/5;
cout << "Nickels: " << nickels << endl;
coin_price = coin_price - (nickels*5);
pennies = coin_price/1;
cout << "Pennies: " << pennies << endl;
coin_price = coin_price - (pennies*1);
}
```

I apologize for the bad formatting of it when I pasted it all in here. The function runs fine by itself, by when the change given back doesn't include a certain bill or coin I don't know how to not include it. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming `twenties` is the number of twenties to return, why not use an if statement: `if (twenties > 0) ...`

Comment: That will definitely work. I'll add that in now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add tests for the coins/notes values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct Currency {
    const char * name;
    int value;
};

Currency values[] = {
    {"Twenty", 2000}, 
    {"Tens", 10000},
    {"Dimes", 10},
    {"Pennies",1}
};

int main() {
    int change = 101;

    for(auto& i: values){
        int units = change /i.value;
        if(units)// test that there is some change with these coins/notes
          std::cout << i.name << units << endl;
         change -= units*i.value;
    }

    return 0;
}
```